# handling fetched data from javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

i need some help with my code
I have this data object which is my data source.

```
    var data = [   {
      "label":"May 7",
      "value":25736.6,
      "proID":"ISB"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 8",
      "value":7893.3,
      "proID":"LI8"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 8",
      "value":30972.3,
      "proID":"ISB"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 9",
      "value":25060.7,
      "proID":"ISB"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 9",
      "value":17920.5,
      "proID":"LI8"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 10",
      "value":16209.8,
      "proID":"LI8"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 10",
      "value":62440.4,
      "proID":"ISB"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 11",
      "value":14433.6,
      "proID":"LI8"
   },
   {
      "label":"May 11",
      "value":48848.5,
      "proID":"ISB"
   }
   ];
```

I'm processing this data to supply my another structure of object:

```
  const labelsAdded = new Set();
  data.forEach(({ label }) => {
    if (labelsAdded.has(label)) {
      return;
    } 
    labelsAdded.add(label);
    propertiesObject.dataSource.categories[0].category.push({ label });
  });
 // alert(labelsAdded.size);
  var propCount = Object.keys(data).length;
  let setLabel = [...labelsAdded];
  for(let i = 0; i < labelsAdded.size; i++) {
     for(let x = 0; x < propCount; x++) {

   if(data[x].proID == 'ISB') {
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[0].data.push({value: data[x].value});
        } 

        if(data[x].proID == 'LI8') {
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[1].data.push({value: data[x].value});
        } 

        if(data[x].proID == 'DAC') {
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[1].data.push({value: data[x].value});
        } 
     } 
}
```

**my question is
how can i dynamically put the extracted data to the correct Date 
example in the data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL3iz.png)**

```
  {
  "label":"May 8",
  "value":7893.3,
  "proID":"LI8"
  }
```

**since this is May 8 it should placed to May 8, but if you check my jsfiddle it's placed to May 7 and it caused my graph to be incorrect because it's just populating my object and not checking if it's the right position to push.**

please check my jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/meraki26/342b6a0w/10/  if my question is not clear, you can see the problem that i mentioned 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var propCount = Object.keys(data).length;
  let setLabel = [...labelsAdded];
  for(let i = 0; i < labelsAdded.size; i++) {
     for(let x = 0; x < propCount; x++) {

        if(data[x].proID == 'ISB') {
            let ndx = Array.from(setLabel).indexOf(data[x].label);
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[0].data.push({value: null});
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[0].data[ndx]=data[x];
        } 

        if(data[x].proID == 'LI8') {
          let ndx = Array.from(setLabel).indexOf(data[x].label);
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[1].data.push({value: null});
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[1].data[ndx]=data[x];
        } 

        if(data[x].proID == 'DAC') {
          let ndx = Array.from(setLabel).indexOf(data[x].label);
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[2].data.push({value: null});
          propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[2].data[ndx]=data[x];
        } 
     }
  }
```

Here I have inserted data only at the same index of the label it works perfect
I also added nulls in the blank spaces
Nice question!

LINK:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ukj6L9q/45/

Comment: thank you so much!!. this is exactly the solution i need

Comment: not as pity as code that doesn't work lol but yeah i had the same idea when i first saw it but i just want it to work i dont care about looks so far

Answer (score 1):

I think your code put all values in all date.
May be this one is correct:

```
var data = [{ label: "May 7",  value: 25736.6, proID: "ISB" }
          , { label: "May 8",  value: 7893.3,  proID: "LI8" }
          , { label: "May 8",  value: 30972.3, proID: "ISB" }
          , { label: "May 9",  value: 25060.7, proID: "ISB" }
          , { label: "May 9",  value: 17920.5, proID: "LI8" }
          , { label: "May 10", value: 16209.8, proID: "LI8" }
          , { label: "May 10", value: 62440.4, proID: "ISB" }
          , { label: "May 11", value: 14433.6, proID: "LI8" }
          , { label: "May 11", value: 48848.5, proID: "ISB" }
          ];

const Prop = { 'ISB': 0,  'LI8': 1,  'DAC': 1 }

const labelsAdded = new Set();

for (let {label} of data)
{
  if (labelsAdded.has(label)) continue 
  labelsAdded.add(label);
  propertiesObject.dataSource.categories[0].category.push({ label });
}

for (let xDate of labelsAdded) 
{
  for( let OnDate of data.filter(d=>d.label===xDate))
  {
    propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[ Prop[OnDate.proID] ].data.push({value: OnDate.value});
  }
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error: TypeError: propertiesObject.dataSource.dataset[Prop[OnDate]] is undefined

Comment: what i mean is, the LI8 should not in may 7 since there's no may 7 in the data only may 8,9,10,11

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand how FusionCharts works, and why you didn't put label value in dataset[].data

Comment: yeah it's my first time using fusionchart and im a bit confused too, but thank you anyway sir i like your short method for loop.